# AngularJS-How can I format a string containing a series of numbers to display as a list on my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have an HTML table that I am dynamically filling out using a couple textboxes. What I would like to do is the following:

Let

$scope.submittedNumbers = 00251212 00254545 00257878 00256565

Display as

00251212

00254545

00257878

00256565

Here is my AngularJS function that adds a row to my HTML table. How can I accomplish this?

```
$scope.addCertificate = function () {

    var certificate = {
        emailAddress: $scope.emailAddress,
        certificateType: $scope.certificateType,
        searchType: $scope.searchType,
        submittedNumbers: $scope.submittedNumbers,
    };

    $scope.requests.push(certificate);
};
```

Comment: Is that a string of numbers or an array? Your code above isn't syntactically valid

Answer (score 1):

you can split it to array in controller:

```
$scope.numbersAsList = $scope.submittedNumbers.split(' ');
```

and after iterate over it with ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="number in numbersAsList">{{ number }}</li>
</ul>
```

after that you can join it again with:

```
var joinedAgain = $scope.numbersAsList.join(' ');
```